# CakePHP Number Validation

Tags: php, cakephp

Is there any cakephp validation for numbers only. That input field should only accept Numbers whether its float OR integer.
I have this field validation in model, But I don't know what rule to use.

```
 'payment_commission' => array(
        'required' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'message' => 'Required.'
        )

    )
```

Any help is much appreciated..

Comment: You'll find all the available CakePHP validation rules in the [docs](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `numeric` to test for valid numbers:-

```
'payment_commission' => array(
    'required' => array(
        'rule' => 'notEmpty', // use notBlank as of CakePHP 2.7
        'message' => 'Required.'
    ),
    'numeric' => array(
        'rule' => 'numeric',
        'message' => 'Numbers only'
    )
)
```

You can alternatively use `decimal` to check for floats or `naturalNumber` for natural numbers. Full details can be found in the [offical docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html).

You can also make sure that the input field only allows for numeric values:-

```
<?= $this->Form->input('payment_commission', ['type' => 'number']) ?>
```

This has the added advantage that on some mobile devices the keyboard will switch to a number pad for easier input. It's important to ensure that the server-side validation (the Cake part) is in place though as there are ways for people to get round client-side validation.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below cakePHP code for number validation.

```
'payment_commission' => array(
    'numeric' => array(
        'required' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'message' => 'Required.'
        )
    ) 
)
```

You can use below html pattern code in for your textbox.

```
<input type="text" name="payment_commission" pattern="[0-9]{10}" title="Three letter country code">
```

Here you can manage your pattern by changing `[0-9]{10}`. (`[0-9]` = expected integers from User, `{10}` = length).

Answer (score 1):

You can use following rule to validate numbers(float and integer):

```
'payment_commission' => array(
    'numeric' => array(
        'rule' => array('decimal', 2),
        'message' => 'Please enter only numbers',
        'allowEmpty' => false,
        'required' => true,
    )
),
```

Let me know if this works for you.